# When I click a .java file, IntelliJ doesn't open it as a class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I click on .java file I have on my computer, IntelliJ won't open it as class, so I can test it. Just red circle appears and that's it. How can I open this as a class? Here is a picture:

[image]

Comment: what is the location of your .java file?It should be part of some Java project and not a random file which will get automatically compiled.Use a -javac commnd line option

Comment: We've gotten a zip file, that contains .java files. We need to solve problems for the lecture. I extracted it on Desktop, and when I click .java files I have problem showed on picture above. Do I need to create a new project and extract my files there or what?

Answer (score 1):

You can not simply open and run the file without creating a project with a java module. This is because to run a class IDEA needs some basic configuration, like JDK, classpath, output path etc.

This icon in your case means that Aufgabe2.java is outside of the configured "source" folders (the "HelloWorld\src" folder marked with blue). Because of that the Aufgabe2.java is not treated as a source file, so it is not compiled and cannot be run.

The simplest option is to copy the file into the "src" folder. Another option is to create brand new project with a java module and to add this file into it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by opening a new project but from an existing source, and choosing the root directory of the project you want to open (in your case the HelloWorld folder):

[image: Project From Existing Sources]

Answer (score 0):

**Aufgabe2.java** is not in the project source directory; add it to **src/** first.

On a side note, when opening a project given a source directory that has not yet been open 
with intellij, first, go to project structure (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), select your project, and in the sources tab, mark source dirs as **source** (blue highlight).